# Match cell content based on line break

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, newlines

I take data from a helpline call in site and transfer it to Linux Libreoffice Calc (LC). 
Column C cells have 2 sets of data - two telephone numbers - 1 being the caller and 1 being the forwarded number that the caller was forwarded to.("1 (4xx) 8xx-3xx2
1 (5xx) 4xx-9xx1")

So does column D have two sets of data - the date and time of the call".

In the LC cell content box on the bar it only displays one number which is the first number "1 (4xx) 8xx-3xx2" only.

I need to delete the second number in all cells in column C so I can do a sort of the data yet cannot separate these two numbers or see the second number on the bar.

Need to know how many times a telephone number came into the helpline.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any rule to separate the two numbers? Is the first a fixed number of characters? Or are they separated by something recognizable (perhaps tab instead of space)?

Comment: In each cell they are stacked,that's all. In the view formula box on the bar just the top number is displayed.

Comment: By two sets of data, date and time, you mean date when it happened and it's duration? Because a date and time when it happened would, fortunately, be just _one_ value.

Comment: Stacked above each other? That means that they are separated by the newline character. That should be easy to take apart, fortunately.

Comment: Hm, I can't find a way to pass a newline char to the `=FIND` function except if I store it in a cell.

Comment: That helps a bit as I just entered a delete after the first number and the second one is displayed and can be deleted. Now have to that 674 times (number of calls to the helpline) and erase the second number. At least it is a start. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Comment: Note, that in LibreOffice the cursor can also be placed in the cell itself and that in cell with multiple lines, up/down moves between lines.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make the line break accessible for **[LibreOffice Calc text functions](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Text_functions)**:

- using **regular expressions**: `"\n"` will match a line break if regular expressions are enabled in formulas (Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`LibreOffice Calc`" -> "`Calculate`" -> "`Enable regular expressions in formulas`");
- without regular expressions, **using the** [**`CHAR()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CHAR_function) **function**: "`CHAR(10)`" matches a line break, too.

Based on this, it's possible to break up cell content (in `C1`) on a line break using the [**`LEFT()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LEFT_function) and [**`RIGHT()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_RIGHT_function) functions in two ways:

- **with regular expressions**, you can determine the position of the line break using the [**`SEARCH()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function) function:

  > `=LEFT(C1;SEARCH("\n";C1)-1)`
  >
  > `=RIGHT(C1;(LEN(C1)-SEARCH("\n";C1;1))+1)`
- **without regular expressions**, you can determine the position of the line break using the [**`FIND()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_FIND_function) function:

  > `=LEFT(C1;FIND(CHAR(10);C1)-1)`
  >
  > `=RIGHT(C1;(LEN(C1)-FIND(CHAR(10);C1;1))+1)`

*NB: To be precise, `SEARCH()` works with `CHAR(10)`, too, but not vice versa - `FIND()` tries to match a literal "`\n`" instead of a line break.*

*NB2: The `+1` and `-1` respectively make sure that the resulting string doesn't contain the line break.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data starts in row 2 and E is first free column (if not, shift appropriately), do:

- <strike>In cell F2, press Ctrl-Enter to enter a newline.</strike>
- In cell E2, enter formula `=LEFT(C2, FIND(CHAR(10), C2))`
- Copy E2 to E2..En where n is the last line.

That should give you the first line of each value.

Getting the second line is a little bit trickier as you need to calculate the number of characters. I think the formula is `=RIGHT(C2, LENGTH(C2) - FIND(CHAR(10), C2) - 1)`.

Note: updated to use `CHAR(10)` as suggested by tohuwawohu.

Comment: Using Left() and Right() is a good approach, so +1 from me - but there are different ways to match a line break in LO Calc fomulas. So i've added another answer concerning that point.